# T-SQL. What is better: join then group or group then join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables:

**Order:**

```
IdProduct (what is ordered - FK to Product table)
Price  (what is the total price for offer)
Piece  (i.e. count - how many products are ordered?)
```

**Product**:

```
Id
Name
```

And there are 2 SQL statements that return products for the best price per item:

Statement #1:

```
SELECT 
    p.Name,
    MIN (Price / Piece) AS MinPrice
FROM 
    [ORDER] o
JOIN 
    Product p ON IdProduct = p.Id
GROUP BY
    p.Name
```

Statement #2:

```
SELECT p.Name, t.MinPrice 
FROM
    (SELECT IdProduct, MIN(Price/Piece) AS MinPrice 
     FROM [Order] 
     GROUP BY IdProduct) t 
JOIN 
    Product p ON p.Id = t.IdProduct
```

I investigated execution plans in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and they look very similar, though I have several observations:

1. Why does the first plan use `[order by name]` instruction? It's output has product names that are ordered "asc" even if I don't use T-SQL Order instruction
2. This implicit "order by name asc" slows down the first sql. When I add "order by name asc" to second sql - they become identical for execution plan cost.
3. I guess that sql #2 should outperfom #1 because of:

   a). It groups by PK (that is integer), not by name (that has `nvarchar` column type, moreover it is not indexed)
   b). It joins tables only after the first one is grouped that should maximize performance (compared to joining full 2 tables as it's expected for the first sql) - but execution plans show the same estimated execution cost nevertheless.

What SQL statement would you prefer and why? May be you have your own version for SQL statement?

Comment: the order by is produced  by the group by  .and have not cost  the group by operation implies the defualt group by  as   .. if you add  an explicit order by . the sql optimizer  should know that is not need  in this case   .. .   In this case the first query is better  .. the second implies the creation of a temporary table

Comment: When it comes to performance questions, it is often useful to run some tests.  For instance, mock up a million rows for testing, capture the start time before the first query, capture the end time after the query runs, then calculate the time it took to execute.  Do the same on the second query.  Might want to run each test 5 times or so to get a few readings on execution time for each query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would prefer statement 2. My reason is quite different from what you would expect.

Have you realized your 2 statements are not built to return the same results?

The 1st query does **NOT** group records by product, it groups them by product name. In most DB out there, columns called `name` are never unique. Therefore, the 2 `GROUP BY` are not equivalent (maybe your test data *happens* to make the 2 results identical but that's only luck playing here).

Here is what should have been written:

```
SELECT 
    p.Name,
    MIN (Price / Piece) AS MinPrice
FROM 
    [ORDER] o
JOIN 
    Product p ON IdProduct = p.Id
GROUP BY
    IdProduct, p.Name /* GROUP BY PK on Product */
```

IMHO, the 2nd syntax is a good protection against that kind of mistake. I advise that is the one you use.
That will save you some troubles when you work on legacy DB with 100+ tables instead of 2 tables you created and filled yourself, not to mention the 1st statement could appear to work correctly for a long time until, finally, `Product.name` becomes non unique.

BTW, the implicit `order by` was hinting it is not using the PK column. It is not slowing down your query. It is ordering records in preparation for the `GROUP BY`

---

PS: to answer your question about performance, your 2nd statement vs the one I have written about should be very similar (thanks to the query planner).
I have sometimes seen the 1st statement to be significantly slower but never significantly faster than the 2nd (if exceptions exist, they are rare enough for me to have missed them).

PPS: Since you aggregate data from `Product`, adding a `WHERE` on a field from `Order` could make things more complicated for performance.
I am afraid that is the kind of things you have to try every single time a new query is being developed.